# Access combobox requery

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have two comboboxs, one is used to control another. So in the AfterUpdate event of the combo_1, I do a requery for combo_2 to force it to update its list according to the value chosen in combo_1. But my code doesn't.

Private Sub combo1_AfterUpdate()

```
Dim strSQL As String

Select Case Me.combo1.Column(1)
    Case "Production"
        Me.combo2.Visible = True
        strSQL = "SELECT id_prod FROM tblProd;"
        Me.combo2.ControlSource = strSQL
        Me.combo2.Requery
    Case Else
        Me.combo2.Visible = False
End Select
```

End Sub

There is nothing in the combo_2 when i choose "Production" in combo_1. The requery clause is executed but no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the syntax has changed in later version you should change the line

```
Me.combo2.ControlSource=strSQL
```

To

```
Me.combo2.RowSource=strSQL
```

Try that because otherwise it looks good

Comment: In fact what's the difference between ControlSource and RowSource?

Comment: One controls what is in the drop down list the other controls what would be displayed if it was a bound form. For example you might have a list of states from a table tblStates in the rows source and the control source would be the state ID column on your sales table